# Can any class of ML algorithms efficiently learn the modulo function (x mod y)?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, supervised-learning

The modulo operator is a non-smooth, non-linear function which has a kind of regularity that is easy to learn by human learners.

`Z = X % Y`

[image: modulo 3d]

However, naive NN approaches to learn the function often encounter problems efficiently learning it.

- [Train a Neural Network to distinguish between even and odd numbers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161189/train-a-neural-network-to-distinguish-between-even-and-odd-numbers)
- [Keras: Making a neural network to find a number's modulus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380303/keras-making-a-neural-network-to-find-a-numbers-modulus)

**Are there any classes of algorithms that are able to efficiently learn the modulo operator and other functions with similar regularity?**

Comment: See this notebook study: https://github.com/HStrand/modulo/blob/master/modulo.ipynb
A standard MLPRegressor seems do a good job to learn the modulo operator. However, it is not clear to me why one wants to learn this operator in practice. If we want to learn some smooth function `f(X) mod Y`, can we just add a last layer as a simple mod operator? Will that make the learning significantly harder because the function gets wrapped around and becomes non-smooth all of sudden? But for the same argument, I do not see how learning this layer by ML would make learning `f(X) mod Y` easier.

Comment: Might be of interest: [Depth  Efficient  Neural Networks for Division and Related Problems (1993)](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/4894171.pdf)

Comment: I think this depends on what one means by "learn". IMO most ML algorithms can memorise the modulus function (within a fixed range), but not generalise to new cases.  I think modulo requires a temporal representation to generalise ( essentialy if you represent numbers as eg a sequence of binary bits)

Comment: I'd also be interested to know why someone would want to do this.  There are always going to be tasks that a particular learning system finds difficult.  All ML systems have inductive bias, but it is also the inductive bias that allows them to be good at some other set of problems without huge amounts of data or resources.

Answer (score 3):

**FOURIER SERIES**

"Not a machine learning algorithm," you say? I disagree. A Fourier series is a linear regression with infinite (nonlinear) features.

$$
\hat y_i = \hat a_0 + \hat a_1\cos\left(
\dfrac{
2\pi \times 1x_i
}{
P
}
\right)
 + \hat b_1\sin\left(
\dfrac{
2\pi \times 1x_i
}{
P
}
\right)
+ \hat a_2\cos\left(
\dfrac{
2\pi \times 2x_i
}{
P
}
\right)
 + \hat b_2\sin\left(
\dfrac{
2\pi \times 2x_i
}{
P
}
\right) +\dots
$$

Even with a finite number of features, you can get as close as you want to the modulo function, which is, ultimately, just a [sawtooth function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave) that we know a Fourier series can approximate well almost everywhere.

For the kind of periodic behavior that the modulo function exhibits, trigonometric functions and Fourier series seem like a natural place to look.

**EDIT**

If you want to have the period be variable (as in $z(x, y) = x\mod y$), perhaps consider an interaction term in the Fourier regression.

Answer (score 2):

The following idea can be salvaged from this paper "Grokking Modular Arithmetic" https://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.02679.pdf. We will construct a two-layer neural network which computes modular reduction exactly. Just as user @Dave's idea, it is based on the Fourier analysis. The difference here is that we will use a finite (but large) number of frequencies.

---

Let $W^{(1)}=(w^{(1)}_{kn})_{k,n}$ be a $K \times N$ and $W^{(2)}=(w^{(2)}_{kn})_{k,r}$ be a $K \times p$ matrix defined by
\begin{align}
    w_{kn}^{(1)} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt K}\cos(\frac{2k\pi}{p}\frac{n}{2} + \frac{\varphi^{(1)}_k}{2}),\text{ for any }k \in [K],\,n \in [N],\\
    w_{kr}^{(2)} &= \cos(-\frac{2k\pi}{p}r - \varphi_k^{(2)}),\text{ for any }k \in [K],\,r \in [p],
\end{align}
the $\varphi_k^{(\ell)}$ are angles which will be specified later. Here $N \ge p$ and we are interested in computing $n \mod p$ for any integer $n \in [0,N]$.
Let $x\in \mathbb R^N$ be the one-hot encoding of $n$. Then, the preactivations of $x$ are given by the vector $h(x) :=W x =(w_{kn})_{k \in [K]} \in \mathbb R^K$ is the $n$ column of $W$. It is clear that
\begin{eqnarray}
    h(x)_k^2 = w_{kn}^2 = \frac{\cos(\frac{2k\pi}{p}n + \varphi_k^{(1)}) + 1}{2K}, 
\end{eqnarray}
where we have used the trigonometric identity $\cos^2 u = (\cos(2u) + 1)/2$.
Finally, one computes the $r$th output of the network as
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{split}
        \Phi(x)_r &= \frac{1}{2K}\sum_k \cos(-\frac{2k\pi}{p}r - \varphi_k^{(2)})\\
         &\quad + \frac{1}{2K}\sum_k \cos(-\frac{2k\pi}{p}r - \varphi_k^{(2)})\cos(\frac{2k\pi}{p}n + \varphi_k^{(1)}).
\end{split}
\end{eqnarray}
Recall the trigonometric identity
\begin{eqnarray}
    \cos(\frac{a+b}{2})\cos(\frac{a-b}{2}) = \frac{\cos a + \cos b}{2}.
\end{eqnarray}
Set $a+b=2u$ and $a-b=2v$, we get $a=u+v$ and $v=a-b$, and so
\begin{eqnarray}
    \cos u \cos v = \frac{\cos(u+v) + \cos(u-v)}{2}.
\end{eqnarray}
Letting $v=-(2\pi k/p)r - \varphi_k^{(2)}$ and $u=(2\pi k/p)n + \varphi_k^{(1)}$, we get
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{split}
    \Phi(x)_r &= (W_2 h(x))_r = \frac{1}{2K}\sum_k \cos(\frac{2k\pi}{p} r + \varphi_k^{(2)})\\
    &\quad + \frac{1}{4K}\sum_k \cos(\frac{2k\pi}{p} (n-r) + \varphi^{(1)}_k - \varphi_k^{(2)})\\
    &\quad + \frac{1}{4K}\sum_k \cos(\frac{2k\pi}{p} (n+r) + \varphi^{(1)}_k + \varphi_k^{(2)}).
\end{split}
\end{eqnarray}
Now let $\varphi_1^{(1)},\ldots,\varphi_K^{(1)}$ be iid uniform on $[-2\pi,2\pi]$ and take $\varphi_k^{(2)} = \varphi_k^{(1)}$ for all $k$. Then, first and third terms are proportional to quantities of the form
$$
\frac{1}{K}\sum_{k=1}^K \cos(\frac{2k\pi}{p}s + a \varphi_k^{(1)}) = O_{\mathbb P}(\sqrt{\log (N)/K}) = o_{\mathbb P}(1),\text{ for }K \gg \log N,
$$
uniformly on all different choices of $s \in [-2N,2N] \cap \mathbb Z$ and $a \in \{1,2\}$. We have used concentration of a Lipschitz function of subGaussian random variables (here, $\log N$ is the "entropy cost" due to union-bound and the Lipschitz constant of the LHS as a function of the vector of the $\varphi^{(1)}_k$'s is $1/\sqrt K$).

On the other hand, one simplifies the 2nd term like so
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{split}
         \frac{1}{4K}\sum_{k=1}^K \cos(\frac{2k\pi}{p}(n-r)) &= 
         \frac{\delta_p(n,r)}{4},\\
         \text{ where }\delta_p(n,q) &= \begin{cases}
             1,&\mbox{ if }n=r\mod p,\\
             0,&\mbox{ else,}
         \end{cases}
\end{split}
\end{eqnarray}
provided $K \ge p$. We conclude that for $K \ge p$ and $K \gg \log N$, it holds w.h.p that
\begin{eqnarray}
    \Phi(x)_r = \frac{\delta_p(n,r)}{4} + O(\sqrt{\frac{\log N}{K}}) \simeq \frac{\delta_p(n,r)}{4}.
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

i would say the answer is 'no', you need a different representation to *generalise* the mod function as opposed to just memorising the mod for a fixed range of numbers.

simple solution (make input the correct output) for eg mod 2, you use some kind  of recurrent neural net with a single input (0/1) (and sequence of inputs represents increasing powers of 2)
then first/last input is the answer.note that  this representation handles all integers.

since recurrent neural networks are turing complete, in theory there is an rnn that could compute the mod function.
whether this is learnable is a different problem!